# scheme theoretic support of a finitely generated $A$-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I was doing Professor Vakil's FOAG, in exercise 9.1M which defines an scheme- theoretic support of a finite generated $A$- module $M$ to be:

the scheme-theoretic intersection of all closed subschemes $\text{Spec } A/I \to \text{Spec } A$ for which $M$ is an $A/I$ module.Show that it is the scheme theoretic union of scheme theoretic supports of any finite generating set of $M$.

---

My attempt: since $M$ is $A/I$ module iff $I \subset \text{Ann}(M)$. therefore the intersection should be $\text{Spec } A/(\text{Ann }M)$. But why bother to consider the intersection of those $\text{Spec } A/I$ instead of defining it directly to be $\text{Spec } A/(\text{Ann }M)$?

Comment: And I found a related question which defines it directly:https://mathoverflow.net/a/34632/97016

Comment: The 'actual definition' of support is the set of primes p of A such that M localized at p is not zero. I have no clue why Vakil does it this way but you're right that it is defined by the ideal (Ann M).

Comment: Got it, thank you Cranium Clamp

Comment: @CraniumClamp This question is about the scheme-theoretic support of a module. Your 'actual definition' is the definition of the set-theoretic support. These are distinct concepts (for example, one is a scheme, and one is just a closed subset), and it is in general not true that the underlying topological space of the scheme-theoretic support is equal to the set-theoretic support.

Comment: @StefanDawydiak everybody knows that. It’s no big deal to put a subscheme structure on the support by the annihilator ideal.